# The code does its job but shows this error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

while testing update post in my mern project it's done fine the post will update but the page disappear and am facing this error and after i restart the server the updated post will be shown like the error never happened

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\ه\Desktop\social-website\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\ه\Desktop\social-website\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\ه\Desktop\social-website\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
at updatePost (file:///C:/Users/%D9%87/Desktop/social-website/backend/controllers/postController.js:140:25)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
```

code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

this is my postController.js code:

```
const updatePost = async(req, res) => {
const postId = req.params.id;
try {
    const post = await Post.findById(postId);
    let { text, img } = req.body;

    console.log(text)
    if(!post) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Post Not found!" })

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    // if(!user) {
    //     return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found!" })
    // }

    if(post.postedBy.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()){
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "You cannot update other user's post" });
    }


    if(user._id.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()){
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized to update post" })
    }

    const maxLength = 500;
    if(text.length > maxLength){
        return res.status(400).json({ error: `Text must be less than ${maxLength} characters!` })
    }
    console.log(post)

    if(img){
        if(post.img){
            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(post.img.split("/").pop().split(".")[0])
        }
        const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img);
        img = uploadedResponse.img;
    }

    const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: postId}, {text, img}, {new: true});
    post.text = text || post.text
    post.img = img || post.img
    if( updatedPost ) res.status(200).json(updatedPost);
    updatedPost = await post.save();


  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Comment: I assume `post.save()` throws. If that is the case, then the previous line sends `res.status(200).json(...)`; then, `post.save()` would throw, and you'd send `res.status(500).json(...)` in the `catch` block: You'd have tried to send headers twice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is occurring because you are trying to send multiple responses to the client within your updatePost function. Specifically, it appears that you are sending a response **(using res.json or res.status)** after certain conditions are met, but then the code continues to execute and sends another response later in the function.

- **At the end of try**

code :

```
return res.status(200).json({ success: true, post });
```

- **At the end of the catch**

code :

```
 return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
```

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that your function exits after sending a response. You can use return after sending a response to stop further execution of the function. Here's a modified version of your code:

- **Code in full**

code :

```
const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  const postId = req.params.id;
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(postId);
    let { text, img } = req.body;

    console.log(text);
    if (!post) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Post Not found!" });

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    
    if (post.postedBy.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "You cannot update other user's post" });
    }

    if (user._id.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized to update post" });
    }

    const maxLength = 500;
    if (text.length > maxLength) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: `Text must be less than ${maxLength} characters!` });
    }
    console.log(post);

    if (img) {
      if (post.img) {
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(post.img.split("/").pop().split(".")[0]);
      }
      const uploaded = // ... your code to upload image

      
      post.text = text;
      post.img = uploaded.secure_url;

      
      await post.save();

     
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, post });
    } else {
      
      post.text = text;

      
      await post.save();

      
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, post });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
```

This code includes return statements after sending responses, which should prevent the "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error.

Comment: now the error is `Assignment to constant variable`

Comment: Has the previous problem been solved? If it is not solved, send the piece of code so that I can check it @khayal

Comment: this error shown in gitbash
`
{
  post object here. . .
}
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at updatePost (file:///C:/Users/%D9%87/Desktop/social-website/backend/controllers/postController.js:123:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) @daniel3380

Comment: I changed some variables from const to let and it appears to me that the post was updated successfully, but nothing changed @daniel3380

Answer (score 0):

i solved it thank you guys i've changed this line:

`const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img); img=uploadedResponse.img;`

to this:

`const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img); img=uploadedResponse.secure_url;`

thanks alot to everyone tried to help me I appreciate it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).